# Implement ROLE based access in Angular2

Tags: javascript, angular, authentication, web, single-sign-on

I have an angular2 application and i have implemented the Registration and Login Modules. User role and other details are received when login in. Have no idea on how to properly manage access, based on the role of the user.

At the moment i'm hoping to use a Angular2 service to share the user role and other details through out the application and use "if" conditions to manage access, based on the Role.

Please provide me any information on how to properly do this.

Answer (score 1):

I would approach this by building out an object to read from when the user is successfully logged in.

```
// when user logs in build out permissions object
permissions = {
  dashboardOne: true,
  dashboardTwo: true
}
```

then within your auth service, have a function that returns a boolean based on the user's permissions

```
userHasAccess = (() =>{
  return {
    toDashboardOne: () => {
      return this.permissions.hasOwnProperty('dashboardOne');
    },
    toDashboardTwo: () => {
      return this.permissions.hasOwnProperty('dashboardTwo');
    }
  }
})();
```

now throughout the app you can call the above function

```
if(this._authService.userHasAccess.toDashboardOne()){
  // do something
}
```

I hope this helps get you started. cheers

Comment: Yes. I can use this as a start.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44640425/7176268 another way to potentially do this. That method is a little more dynamic, but I prefer the above since an IDE will list out the available options.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use [ngx-permissions](https://github.com/AlexKhymenko/ngx-permissions) library for controlling of permissions and roles in your angular application. The benefits it will remove elements from DOM, **lazy loading and isolated modules supported(then, else syntax is supported).**
Example of loading roles

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NgxPermissionsService } from 'ngx-permissions';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  title = 'app';

   constructor(private permissionsService: NgxPermissionsService,
               private http: HttpClient) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    NgxRolesService
    .addRole('ROLE_NAME', ['permissionNameA', 'permissionNameB'])

    NgxRolesService.addRole('Guest', () => {
       return this.sessionService.checkSession().toPromise();
    }); 

    NgxRolesService.addRole('Guest', () => {
     return true;
    }); 
  }
}
```

Usage in templates

```
<ng-template [ngxPermissionsOnly]="['ADMIN']" (permissionsAuthorized)="yourCustomAuthorizedFunction()" (permissionsUnauthorized)="yourCustomAuthorizedFunction()">
    <div>You can see this text congrats</div>
 </ng-template>
<div *ngxPermissionsOnly="['ADMIN', 'GUEST']">
    <div>You can see this text congrats</div>
</div>

 <div *ngxPermissionsExcept="['ADMIN', 'JOHNY']">
   <div>All will see it except admin and Johny</div>
 </div>
```

for more information see [wiki page](https://github.com/AlexKhymenko/ngx-permissions/wiki)

Comment: I see that it was implemented by you. I'll check this out.

Comment: Hi, I can't get the wiki code working. There are typos for the loadPermissions snippet. and I get an error for permissions object due: Argument of type 'Object' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string[]'.
  The 'Object' type is assignable to very few other types. Did you mean to use the 'any' type instead?
    Property 'includes' is missing in type 'Object'.