# How to provide user role to ngx-permissions in Angular 2/4

Tags: angular

I am trying to implement ngx-permissions as mentioned in the Stackoverflow article https://stackoverflow.com/a/45866966/8601771 but I don't know what to implement for

> (permissionsAuthorized)="yourCustomAuthorizedFunction()"

(permissionsUnauthorized)="yourCustomAuthorizedFunction() is this mandatory. How are the User roles getting passed to the tag?

```
    <div>You can see this text congrats</div>
 </ng-template>
<div *ngxPermissionsOnly="['ADMIN', 'GUEST']">
    <div>You can see this text congrats</div>
</div>

 <div *ngxPermissionsExcept="['ADMIN', 'JOHNY']">
   <div>All will see it except admin and Johny</div>
 </div>
```

In the above code where is the User Login credentials getting set?

Answer (score 1):

"permissionsAuthorized" is just event that will be called when element will show up. For example, you need to show message when user have permissions if you don't need it don't implement it. Admin, Guest it's User roles.

For documentation visit [ngx-permissions wiki](https://github.com/AlexKhymenko/ngx-permissions/wiki).

To load role you should write

```
constructor(private ngxRolesService: NgxRolesService) {}

addRole() {
 this.ngxRolesService.addRole('Guest', () => {
  return true
}); 
}
```